# if scroll down to div make div sticky

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I have fullpage.js setup. When adding js to a div, which will activate on scroll down to the div. the div stays fixed to the top. But nothing happens on scroll down.

I am not sure if its because there is no scroll for fullpage.js. but i can not get it to work.

Can it be set to a section instead? if it enters "#secondPage" swap class?

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {  
  var top = $('.sticky-scroll-box').offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {

      if (this.scrollTop > 145) 

      $('.sticky-scroll-box').addClass('fixedlogo');
    else
      $('.sticky-scroll-box').removeClass('fixedlogo');
    $('.sticky-scroll-box').width($('.sticky-scroll-box').parent().width());
  });
});
</script>
```

html

```
<div id="myContainer">
    <div class="section section-one" id="section1">
        <div class="fp-bg"></div>
            <div class="slide1block">
                <div class="slogonblock sticky-scroll-box">
                                    <img id="logo" src="/images/logo/logosmallg.svg">

                </div>
                <div class="introblock">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
                    sed doeiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
                    aliqua. Ut enimad minim veniam, qudr</p>
                </div>
                <div class="linkblock">
                    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><span class="arrow" id="rotate"></span><a class="linkblockf"  href="#secondPage">CLIENT PLATFORM</a></li>
                    <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><span class="arrow" id="rotate"></span><a class="linkblockf" href="#3rdPage">COUNTRY PROGRAMS</a></li>
                    <li data-menuanchor="4thpage"><span class="arrow" id="rotate"></span><a class="linkblockf" href="#4thpage">REAL INVESTMENTS</a></li>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="titleblock"><h1 class="titleblockf">Golden Visa&nbsp; | &nbsp;Investments</h1></div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.fixedlogo {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  z-index:99999;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: hi thank you for your help. i updated your request for code.

Comment: no errors in console. do you use fullpage.js?

Answer (score 0):

Read the [fullPage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions) and you'll find the why and the solution to it:

> **Short answer:** use the scrollBar:true option for fullPage.js or autoScrolling:false if you don't want to use the auto-scrolling feature.
>
> **Explanation:** Parallax, as well as many other plugins which depends on the scrolling of the site, listens the scrollTop property of javascript and the scroll event. fullPage.js doesn't actually scroll the site but it changes the top or translate3d property of the site. Only when using the fullPage.js option scrollBar:true or autoScrolling:false it will actually scroll the site in a way it is accessible for the scrollTop property.

If you really don't want to use a scrollbar, then just make use of the callbacks fullpage.js provides, such as `onLeave` and `afterLoad`.
Read more about them in [the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks).

That would be the proper way of doing what you want to accomplish.